# Install custom theme in Drupal using composer

Tags: drupal

I couldn't install custom theme on drupal 8/9 using composer. This kind of error faced
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

Now how can I solve it?

**Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.our text**

Comment: Share the error - generally for installing package with composer `lando composer require drupal/package-name` now there can be dependency or `PHP` version issues

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Lando, maybe you are missing information about node in lando.yml.
Example:

```
services:
node:
  type: 'node:10'
 build:
   - gulp
 Globals:
   gulp-cli: latest
```